# Unable to install Couchbase sync gateway

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am trying to install Couchbase sync gateway using the steps from the following URL for MacOS
https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/installation/sync-gateway/index.html

This issue is, i downloaded "couchbase-sync-gateway-enterprise_1.4.1-3_x86_64.tar.gz" and its in "Downloads" folder in MacBook.

When I execute this command -> sudo tar -zxvf couchbase-sync-gateway-enterprise_1.4.1-3_x86_64.tar.gz --directory /opt

[MyMacbook:downloads administrator$ sudo tar -zxvf couchbase-sync-gateway-enterprise_1.4.1-3_x86_64.tar.gz --directory /opt

tar: could not chdir to '/opt']

Throws error as "tar: could not chdir to '/opt'"

I don't understand how to resolve this. I couldn't get help anywhere.

Please help installing Couchbase sync gateway successfully on MacBook.

Answer (score 1):

It dosen't actually matter if /opt does not exist on your Mac. You can either create one before firing the command with the following command:

```
sudo mkdir /opt
```

Otherwise, you can replace "opt" with locations like : /Users/< your_user > or /usr/share or /var